# Async Await To Bind Grid

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I am trying to bind a `gridview` in a separate thread.

Almost every example uses `await Task.Delay(10000);` when they are describing a long running task, but i actually want to do some work here.

How do i bind to a grid async (or any work in general) ?

```
private async void BindGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string result = await BindFileGridTemp();
        RadMessageBox.Show(result);

}

public async Task<string> BindFileGridTemp() // Bind Grid
{ 


       // Bind Grid here.........
       //this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = null;
       //this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.ToList()

       await Task.Delay(10000); // I dont want this but its on every example for async and await
       return "I am finished"; 

 }
```

Comment: Bind the grid to something (like a property--implementing INotifyPropertyChanged) then do you work, and *after* the await, set the property.

Comment: You can't really await on a data bind because it has to run on the UI thread. You *could* await on pulling the data from wherever it's coming from, but the actual binding *must* happen on the UI thread

Comment: Creating a new task for it is not a good idea but you can try `public async Task<string> BindFileGridTemp() 
        {
            this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = await Task.Run(() => MyGlobals.ListOfItemsToControl.ToList());
            return "I am finished";
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to bind a gridview in a separate thread.

As others have noted, you can't actually do the binding in another thread; it must be the UI thread.

> Almost every example uses await Task.Delay(10000); when they are describing a long running task, but i actually want to do some work here.

`await Task.Delay` is the asynchronous equivalent of `Thread.Sleep`. It just means "put whatever asynchronous work you have to do here".

> How do i bind to a grid async (or any work in general) ?

It can be as simple as this:

```
public async Task<string> BindFileGridAsync()
{ 
  this.radGridViewFiles.DataSource = await GetMyDatasourceAsync();
  return "I am finished"; 
}
```

Note that this is not in line with the MVVM pattern. To follow the MVVM pattern, implement Peter Ritchie's suggestion: data-bind the `RadGridView.DataSource` XAML attribute to a ViewModel property, start the asynchronous operation when the ViewModel is created, and update the property with the resulting value. If you are doing asynchronous data-binding, I have a [blog post that may help](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html).